# How to invert Javascript element bubble order?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, modal-dialog, event-bubbling

I have created a custom Slider component that works perfectly except for one issue.

If it is present in a modal, then the `mouseUp` event for it fires on it for all events below it (z-index-wise) before on the element itself.

This is because to have a nice slider you need to attach the `mouseMove` and `mouseUp` events to the document instead of the slider itself so that you can still move the thumb and capture mouse up events even when the mouse moves off the slider while sliding the thumb.

As a result, I am now having issues where the `mouseUp` event causes the click events for elements below it to run before the slider element. This causes issues like buttons below it clicking and the modal closing (since these are both click events).

A potential solution is to just add checks to all the potential event handlers that might be intercepted (something like `if (thisModalOpened) { return false; }` to all the various other elements), but that solution seems a bit messy.

Is there any better way? A way to invert the bubbling order seems like it could work, because then I could just call `stopPropagation` in the `mouseUp` for the Slider component. However, I'm not sure if that can be done, because currently the event listener is registered in the document so that it can be detected outside of the element itself.

Some code snippets:

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener("pointermove", this.onThumbMove, false);
  document.addEventListener("pointerup", this.onThumbUp, false);
}

onThumbDown = e => {
  this.setState({ dragging: true, startX: this.getX(e) });
}

onThumbMove = e => {
  if (this.state.dragging) {
    this.setState({ position: e.clientX });
  }
}

onThumbUp = e => {
  if (this.state.dragging) {
    let value = this.getValue();

    this.setState({ dragging: false }, () =>
      this.props.onSubmit(value);
    });
  }
}

<div onPointerDown={this.onThumbDown} ref={this.sliderRef}>
  <div>+</div>
</div>
```

**Edit:** Okay, I think I have finally figured out the problem (but I don't know the solution yet): So, modals often (mine does as well) have the tinted black backdrop that you can click on to close the modal easily. I can either have that black backdrop as a direct parent or a parent's sibling of the model's contents.

If I have it as a direct parent, then I have to call `stopPropagation / return false` on literally every single possible child component, so that clicking them doesn't cause the click to propagate up and click the backdrop modal and cause it to close. So I don't want it as a parent because that's a huge hassle.

On the other hand, if I have it as a parent's sibling, then I cannot call `stopPropagation` on the document `thumbUp` event, because the modal backdrop mask is not a direct parent, so it will be registered as a click and close the modal despite the `stopPropagation` call, because it's not a direct parent.

Basically, both approaches don't work. I don't know how to reconcile this.

Comment: Yes, you can. Please post your current event listener and other relevant code snippets.

Comment: Sure thing. Sec.

Comment: Possibly you can reverse event bubbling phase by passing `true` as the third argument to `event listner`, like `elem.addEventListener("mouseup", function () {
  console.log("mouseup event");
}, true);`

Comment: @SarveshMahajan I tried that but it didn't seem to work. It's registered the document, so setting that to `true` just sends it to the document first (which is already happening). Ideally I'd be able to register it to the document but have it start at the Slider component.

Comment: The default bubbling is exactly what you would have wanted if the buttons are parents of the slider, not capture. There is something else going on here,especially if you are testing it on mobile. Call stopPropagation and stopImmediatePropagation together to make sure no emulated events are firing. And since mouseup and every other emulated events are fired AFTER touch events, you need to call it in touchmove and touchend as well.

Comment: I think I might have found the issue.. For some reason the `thumbUp` event is not firing unless I don't drag at all. That is, it only fires if I tap, not if I thumb down -> drag -> thumb up. I think this is causing issues with regard to the `dragging` boolean. Also, `thumbUp` fires twice when the thumb is released..

Comment: @ibrahimtanyalcin I believe I have figured out the issue (but not the solution). I have edited the OP with more information.

Answer (score 1):

As @Sarvesh mentioned in the comments, you can add a third argument to your event listener but instead of passing a boolean, you need to use the `capture` option to fire events from top to bottom instead of bottom to top as you wanted like this:

```
document.addEventListener("pointerup", this.onThumbUp, { capture: true });
```

You can now add a `stopPropagation()` at the `mouseUp` event or at any other event depending on what you want.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Could it be a mobile issue (it only seems to be happening on mobile)? The click events still activate for the elements below it, even with these inclusions that you mention.

Comment: The above code works just on desktop or doesn't work on both desktop and mobile?

Comment: Well, I never have had this problem at all on desktop (although maybe it's just not noticeable because the desktop is so fast). It only seems to be afflicting my mobile browsers. I have narrowed it down to the `onThumbUp` handler though, because if I stick a `return false;` on the first line there, it fixes the problem (but prevents the slider thumbUp from working, obviously.)

Comment: Hold on. Let me try to figure this out.

Comment: And if possible, could you replicate your app in this boilerplate react sandbox for me? [CodePen Sandbox](https://codepen.io/pen?template=vvRRNg). I have a feeling that it could be something else causing the issue now because the capture option reverses the bubbling as you wanted.

Comment: No I am not getting any console errors. I'll try to replicate it but it may take quite a while.

Comment: I believe I have figured out the issue (but not the solution). I have edited the OP with more information

Comment: @RyanPeschel Can you post the html of the modal along with it's backdrop, etc.